# Best way to "re-create" raw 256-byte UDP frame in python?

Tags: python

I'm not quite sure what is the best approach in recreating an UDP frame in python...one thing that came up to my mind is creating classes with `__init__` methods and the other way is just literally create a dictionary. Basicly the frame is split in 5 pieces:

First 4 bytes (0-3) are used for header description.

Next 32 bytes (4-35) are used for common data.

Next 16 bytes (36-51) are all empty.

Next 4 bytes (52-55) are used for description of payload.

Last 200 bytes are used for payload.

First 4 pieces (header, common, 16-byte empty, payload description) are all parsed from bunch of other files while the payload is given in plain list of `int`.

What would be the best approach in recreating the frame piece by piece? This following snippet is the first idea:

```
class common:
    def __init__(self, par1, par2):
        self.par1 = par1
        self.par2 = par2

class header:
    def __init__(self, par1, par2):
        self.par1 = par1
        self.par2 = par2

class empty:
    def __init__(self):
        self.par1 = 16*[[0]]

class description:
    def __init__(self, par1, par2):
        self.par1 = par1
        self.par2 = par2

class udp_frame:
    def __init__(self, payload, h_par_1, h_par_2, c_par_1, c_par_2, d_par_1, d_par_2,):
        self.payload = payload
        self.header = header(h_par_1, h_par_2)
        self.common = common(c_par_1, c_par_2)
        self.empty = empty()
        self.description = description(d_par_1, d_par_2)

    def create_frame(self):
        temp = [self.header.par1,
                self.header.par2,
                self.common.par1,
                self.common.par2,
                self.empty.par1,
                self.description.par1,
                self.description.par2,
                self.payload
                ]
        while len(temp) < 256:
            temp.extend(0)

        return bytearray(temp)
```

Is there any other more eye-appealing / efficient / standardized way of doing this kind of stuff?

Comment: What you're thinking about has been available for some time now in the form of ScaPy: https://scapy.net/

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look, thanks!